# 2 Column List - Recursive Value Replacement - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have a long list of products that have been obsoleted and replaced by other products. The table has 2 columns: OriginalItem, SubstituteItem.

I want to create a list that would keep the OriginalItem but replace the SubtituteItem with the most recent substitution. So if the SubstitueItem is in the OriginalItem column, it would be replaced. This could happen 1 time or 20 times, which is the part I am having difficulty with.

Example - Original List

```
car1, car2    
car2, car3    
car3, car4
```

Expected Result

```
car1, car4    
car2, car4    
car3, car4
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: do you have a column that specifies order of substitution?

Comment: Sadly no, no dates of when it took place either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) to do this. Something like the following should get you in the ballpark:

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    --recursive seed (Starting point) which will be every record in this case
    SELECT
        originalitem,
        substituteitem,
        1 as depth --track how many iterations
        CAST(originalitem + '>' + substituteitem AS NVARCHAR(500)) as path --track the full path from original item to substitute for fun
    FROM yourtable

    UNION ALL

    --recursive term (gets called over and over again until the join fails)
    SELECT
        recCTE.originalItem,
        yourtable.substituteitem,
        recCTE.depth + 1, --increment depth
        recCTE.path + ">" + yourtable.substituteitem --add to the path
    FROM
        recCTE  --this CTE provides the foundation for this statement because it's recursive
        INNER JOIN youttable ON
            recCTE.substituteitem = yourtable.originalitem --joining sub to orig
    WHERE depth < 20 --just in case of cycling
)
SELECT * FROM reccCTE;
```

Comment: Thanks! I have never used the RECURSIVE function and it is throwing errors after i replaced the table and column names. Am I supposed to replace the recCTE with something?

Comment: recCTE is sort of like an alias, so there is no need to change that. I wrote this without testing, so I suspect there will be some issues. What errors are you receiving?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'recCTE'.

Comment: That what I thought, I looked through it and couldn't find anything specifically wrong about it, I added a comma after the 1st "depth" but that's about it.

Comment: I've updated the answer to remove the `RECURSIVE` keyword. Can you give that a run and see if you get through that error.